# Fix a renamed git-flow branch

Tags: git, branch, rename, git-flow, sourcetree

I renamed my local git flow feature branch, using SourceTree.

Now I want to finish the feature, but git flow tells me that the branch doesn't exist. It does of course, but git flow doesn't recognise it.

How can I make git flow recognise the branch I'm on as a feature branch, so that I can finish it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you rename it from feature/xxxxxx to xxxx. If you remove the feature prefix then gitflow won't know that it is a feature branch, and when it comes to trying to merge it, it won't have a clue. I suggest you make sure it has feature/ on the front of it.